# How to install PMD Pico Flexx camera drivers in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, usb-3, camera

I have PMD Pico Flexx CamBoard camera and I want to install the driver for Windows 10 64bit. There's no driver for Windows 10 however but in one of the machines in our lab, the drivers are installed for Windows 10. How should I install it? I get this error that camera couldn't be open.
[image]

[image]

In the other machine that PMD camera works, it is shown in the Device Manager as PMD Devices.

Comment: These other machines also running Windows 10?

Comment: yes the other machine runs Win10 64 bit and I can see "PMD Device" in the "Device Manager"

Comment: How did you get them working on these other machines?

Comment: I was installed on those machines. I have not installed it!

Comment: What? You indicated the devices are being initialized properly on some machines.  So what did you do on those machines that your doing differently on then machines where the devices are not being properly initialized?

Answer (score 1):

In case this can be helpful to someone:

I reached out to PMD tec and received the answer below. Worked perfectly for me, using Royale 3.19 on a Windows 10 machine.

"We are working on a fix which will be there with release 3.21. In the meantime there is a workaround:

1. Open Device Manager
2. Double click on the camera and choose update drive on tab Driver
3. Search for driver software on the PC
4. Open installation folder of royale , subfolder  "driver\win7\x64"  or  "driver\win7\x86" @ 32Bit Win10. Default path should be "C:\Program Files\royale\3.19.0.60\driver\win7\x64". Install this driver.

"